# How do I remove the box symbol that shows up for a line break when I output a string to a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform where the user enters a description of their project into a textbox and it is stored in a string.  When the user runs the "Generate Report" routine that string is output to a single cell.  If the user entered line breaks, they are present in the output, but there is also a "box" character for each line break.  I can manually delete the "box" character and the line break is still there in the cell, but how do I prevent the "box" character from showing up in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is probably carrying a vbCrLf (Carriage Return + Line Feed). All you need to do is remove the CR of the CR+LF.

Try this:

```
(YourCell.Value Here) = Replace(YourString, vbCrLf, vbLf)
```

Good luck.